# How can I create an inclined cylinder with catia v5r19?

Tags: catia, sketching

I would like to create an inclined cylinder with catia v5 but I don't know how. Anyone has 
an idea of this task? I'm also wondering if I have to draw an inclined plane before the drawing of the cylinder.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: @duffymo The OP was able to attach the appropriate tags for the question. So, I think it is a good fit for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

This is a design question, use of software...an answer you can find in CATIA forums. If you want to know how to do it by programming in CATSCript or catvba (or something else), please specify.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is a design question. What happen if I will give the answer right here.

So...you can do in two ways this construction

1. You can choose an inclined plan already and make the sketch on this plan (circle with diameter) and the extrusion will make following a straight direction
2. after you create the sketch, in extrusion you can choose the inclined direction, so, you can do the sketch on a plan but the direction of extrusion is not perp. on this plane, you can follow an inclined direction.